# Micro stutters on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I just got a new laptop, an Acer Aspire 5 with 4xIntel i7 (10th gen), a Geforce MX350 and 16gb RAM. I also have Ubuntu 20.04.

I very often (always when doing something slightly demanding like opening a new webpage, or playing a game) have graphics stuttering (but not audio) with my mouse freezing for very little time every five seconds or so. I noticed that the Software Updater says I have manually installed Nvidia drivers and I can't seem to find out how to revert to the proprietary ones. What do I do about this? This obviously makes any kind of game unplayable. One thing I've also noticed is the laptop getting very hot after little time, but I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should try to keep open a resource monitor like `htop` to get a better idea of what's going on. It might have nothing to do with your graphics. It might be something simple like a backlog of updates.  The heat you're experiencing is a tradeoff for the high end hardware-- i7 + dedicated GPU + small chassis. When pushed, I've seen laptops produce so much heat at the bottom that it can burn skin.

Comment: Your system also has what's called "hybrid graphics", which is a term you should include in your research. The dedicated GPU is likely working in tandem with the iGPU